Publication trend (quality vs quantity) after tenure
Are there any studies that measure the change or the lack thereof in the trend of publications produced by a professor after they got tenured? Do recently tenured professors shift from quantity of publications to seeking higher quality publications?
I found the following two related questions but:

Are there studies testing whether academia rewards researchers based on number of publications?
This question is broad in scope and doesn't focus on the element of job security provided by tenure status.

How did you or your advisor’s behavior change after obtaining tenure
This question asks in a broader sense about the change due to tenure, which I guess includes publications too, but the question and the answer do not focus on or even mention publications.



In the wonderful spoof journal Journal of Polymorphous Perversity there was once an article with a title something like "Effect of Tenure on Publication Rate".  The article was blank.

Another related question: Any data for average number of papers per year at different career stages?
